# How to create bindable command for custom component in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've a custom component where I've button and I'm trying to create a bindable command so that I can perform action based on viewmodel.
I've tried few things but nothing seems to be working :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MySample), null);

public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}

// Helper method for invoking commands safely
public static void Execute(ICommand command)
{
    if (command == null) return;
    if (command.CanExecute(null))
    {
        command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [implement `propertychanged` for bindable property to enable binding.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes)

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Command), typeof(MySample), null, propertychanged: OnCommandPropertyChanged);

stativ void OnCommandPropertyChanged  (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    (bindable as MySample).Command = (Command)newValue;
}
```

Comment: Tried it now working!! Binded command like : Command={Binding NextCommand} on xaml after applying propertyChanged event.

Comment: Great. If this solved your issue, please upvote and accept. That will help other users with same question.

Comment: Hey !! I 've tried the same thing for entry but it's not working . I have added property changed event as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TapGestureRecognizer` to trigger `Command`:

```
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{
    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var gestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

        gestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
            if (Command != null && Command.CanExecute(null))
            {
                Command.Execute(null);
            }
        };

        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(gestureRecognizer);
    }
    // BindableProperty implementation
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(View1), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Helper method for invoking commands safely
    public static void Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        if (command == null) return;
        if (command.CanExecute(null))
        {
            command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Custom-Command) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Its more like creating behavior on whole view instead of particular elements.

Answer (score 0):

```html
public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static BindableProperty MyCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                 propertyName: "Command",
                                                 returnType: typeof(ICommand),
                                                 declaringType: typeof(View1),
                                                 defaultValue: null,
                                                 defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                 propertyChanged: MyCommandPropertyChanged);

        public static void MyCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CustomSignInTemplate)bindable;
            control.tempbtn.Command = (ICommand)newValue;
        }
```